Confusion on product $\sigma$-algebras
A fairly common misconception is that

"All subsets of $A\times B$ are of the form $A'\times B'$ for $A'\subset A$ and $B'\subset B$"

And the counterexample I usually see is the situation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the line $y=x$, namely $\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ Clearly this cannot be written in the form of $X\times Y$ for any subsets $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}$.
When learning about product $\sigma$-algebras, I kept the above example in mind when trying to understand their definition. The definition I first saw in Folland's Real Analysis was  $$\otimes \mathcal{M}_\alpha:=
\mathcal{M}(\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}): E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A \})
$$ where $\pi_\alpha$ are the projection maps. In countable indices, this is equivalent to $$\otimes \mathcal{M}_{n}=\mathcal{M}(\{\prod_{n}E_n: E_{n} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}\})$$
When considering $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\otimes \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R},$ I am unable to come up with how to generate the set $\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ using either definition above, because no countable collection of rectangles can cover it.
My confusion arose from the following theorem in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples,

Theorem 2.1.10. If for $1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m(i), X_{i, j}$ are independent and $f_i: \mathbf{R}^{m(i)} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ are measurable then $f_i\left(X_{i, 1}, \ldots, X_{i, m(i)}\right)$ are independent.

In particular, suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ a measurable space and $X,Y$ are real-valued r.v.s on $\Omega$, and some measurable $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ pulls back some Borel set $B$ to the line $y=x$. Then when looking at the preimage $\{f(X,Y)\in B\}$ how exactly would $X,Y$ each pull back the line into $\mathcal{F}$ coordinate-wise?

Can you get a little box around $(1,1)$? Can you get a bunch of boxes covering ${(x,x) ,:, x\in \mathbb{R}}$? Can you make them smaller and smaller?

@JamieRadcliffe Wouldn't that have to be an uncountable union of boxes though? If there's countably many, there must be some box containing $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ for $x\ne y$, and thus that box contains $(x,y)$ so its not equal to our set, I thought

@modz You can cover the line with a countable union of boxes, although as you say this union won't be equal to the line. But what happens if we then take the intersection as the boxes get smaller?

@raj Since it's a decreasing sequence, wouldn't the eventual intersection just be the limit as the size of the boxes goes to 0? In which case, wouldn't you eventually start to get holes? That is, as long as any two boxes overlap, there must be extra points in our set. But if two boxes don't overlap, then there is a real in between them that isn't included in our set. And then if you were to "shift" up and down along $y=x$, taking the intersection would just be a strictly smaller set and so it would still have that hole. I think I am not able to properly visualize this construction

One box can contain two smaller ones....

If ${q_i}$ is an enumeration of the rationals, then say we have boxes $B_i(k):=(q_i-k^{-1},q_i+k^{-1})^2$ for $k\geq1$. Let $B(k)=\cup_{i\geq1}B_i(k)$ cover the line $x=y$. Then for any real we have $(x,y)\in \cap_{k\geq1}B(k)\iff (x,y)\in B(k)$ for all $k\iff$ for all $k$ $|(x,y)-(q_i,q_i)|<1/k$ for some $i.$ And then the perpendicular distance from $(x,y)$ to the line can only be at most $|(x,y)-(q_i,q_i)|$ for any $i$ (with equality if the closest point on the line is a rational), so the distance to the line goes to 0. Is this valid?
